# Android NDK build

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-3.0

While trying to build my android ndk project getting following error.
Android studio version 3.1.3

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.

  > Process 'command '/Users/bnaskar/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/bnaskar/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>           at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:382)
>           at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction.execute(DefaultExecAction.java:31)
>           at org.gradle.api.tasks.AbstractExecTask.exec(AbstractExecTask.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:780)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:747)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>           ... 29 more

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
15 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 14 up-to-date
jampp-MacBook-Pro:BreakOut kllu$ ./gradlew installDebug --stacktrace

My build.gradle fie

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bnn.breakout"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        //testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

        sourceSets.main {
            jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
            //jniLibs.srcDir "src/main/libs"
        }
        task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
            commandLine "/Users/bnnk/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build",
                    'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
                    'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
                    'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
                    'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
        }
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
        }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I am afraid you use the deprecated way of building native libraries for your project. The new Android plugin (v. 3.1.2) uses `externalNativeBuild`. See the [official instructions for upgrading](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental/migrate-to-stable).

In the nutshell, you need something like

```
android { 
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "Android.mk"
        }
    }
}
```

in your module **build.gradle**.

## For your file, the result could be as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bnn.breakout"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        //testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
      ndkBuild {
        path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
      }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Make sure your Android plugin is up to date, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50953301/192373

Comment: have added my module gradle file. It used to work in old android studio but with studio up-gradation it seems facing some issue without much information!!!