# Errors updating from NDK version 16 to NDK version 17

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

This is for an Android project using JNI with the NDK.  I'm building the project with Android Studio 3.0.1.  I recently updated my NDK from version 16 to version 17 in the hopes of making more compiler optimizations available.  After the update, I'm getting the following errors:

> CMake Error at C:/Users/John/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:312 (message):
>     Invalid Android ABI: armeabi.  (armeabi is no longer supported.  Use
>     armeabi-v7a.)
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     C:/Users/John/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:98 (include)
>     CMakeLists.txt
>   CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
>   CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
>   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I'm getting this error for each of the deprecated ABIs armeabi, mips, and mips64.  I understand that I should remove these ABIs from the build, but I can't find instructions on how to do that.  I'm not using an Application.mk and I don't see the ABIs being specified anywhere; how can I remove these unused ABIs from my Android Studio project, or better yet, how can I set my project to just use the current non-deprecated ABIs?  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be enough to upgrade your gradle plugin to 3.1.2 or higher, in root (project) **build.gradle** script. Using the latest plugin is recommended not only to be compliant with latest NDK:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
  }
}
```

You also must change **gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip v.4.4
```

If you cannot afford such change, you may try to skip the deprecated ABIs for build and packaging:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    ndk {
      abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a'
    }
  }

  packagingOptions {
    doNotStrip '*/mips/*.so'
    doNotStrip '*/mips64/*.so'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex.  I'm getting "Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2."  I have a notice that says "Platform and Plugin Updates\nAndroid Studio is ready to update" - should I go ahead and try that?

Comment: Or there's another link that says "Add Google Maven repository and sync project" - I guess that's my better option?

Comment: Alright, after spending a big chunk of time updating everything and googling other errors that come up, I'm able to build again - and of course, the new compiler still doesn't support -march=native.  Sigh.  Anyway, your advice helped so I'm marking yours as the correct answer, thank you.

Comment: I believe that NDK takes care of choosing the optimization options quite well for each ABI and platform, so `-march=native` is probably not necessary here.